# Why do these xml files get different responses?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xmlhttprequest

Do these two xml files mean the same thing?

First file:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <S:Body>
      <ProcessData xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
         <document><request xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
        <hotelChain>Disney</hotelChain>
        <processType>ModifyGuest</processType>
        <hotelLineId>ASMU03042015</hotelLineId>
        <firstName>NICOLE</firstName>
        <lastName>ROLAIN</lastName>
        <numberOfBags>1</numberOfBags>
        <status>enrolled</status>
        <hotelGuestId>41955886</hotelGuestId>
        <room>5613</room>
        <eligible>1</eligible>
        <partyGroupId>0</partyGroupId>
        <arrivalDate>2015-02-26</arrivalDate>
        <departureDate>2015-03-04</departureDate>
        <segments>
          <segment>
              <carrier>WN</carrier>
              <flightNumber>4280</flightNumber>
              <departureCity>MCO</departureCity>
              <departureDate>2015-03-04</departureDate>
              <departureTime>12:00 PM</departureTime>
              <operation>Add</operation>
           </segment>
        </segments>
    </request>
    </document>
      </ProcessData>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    <soap:Body>
      <ProcessDataResponse xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
         <ProcessDataResult>
            <response xmlns="">Invalid Process Type</response>
         </ProcessDataResult>
      </ProcessDataResponse>    </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>
```

Second file:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:onv="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
   <S:Body>
      <onv:ProcessData>
         <onv:document><request>
        <hotelChain>Disney</hotelChain>
        <processType>ModifyGuest</processType>
        <hotelLineId>ASMU03042015</hotelLineId>
        <firstName>NICOLE</firstName>
        <lastName>ROLAIN</lastName>
        <numberOfBags>1</numberOfBags>
        <status>enrolled</status>
        <hotelGuestId>41955886</hotelGuestId>
        <room>5613</room>
        <eligible>1</eligible>
        <partyGroupId>0</partyGroupId>
        <arrivalDate>2015-02-26</arrivalDate>
        <departureDate>2015-03-04</departureDate>
        <segments>
          <segment>
              <carrier>WN</carrier>
              <flightNumber>4280</flightNumber>
              <departureCity>MCO</departureCity>
              <departureDate>2015-03-04</departureDate>
              <departureTime>12:00 PM</departureTime>
              <operation>Add</operation>
           </segment>
        </segments>
    </request>
    </onv:document>
      </onv:ProcessData>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ProcessDataResponse xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
         <ProcessDataResult>
            <response xmlns="">OK</response>
         </ProcessDataResult>
      </ProcessDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I thought both these XML files represent same information. But when I hit the SOAP web service using these two files I get a different response.

I also tried this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:onv="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
   <S:Body>
      <onv:ProcessData>
         <onv:document><onv:request>
        <onv:hotelChain>Disney</onv:hotelChain>
        <onv:processType>ModifyGuest</onv:processType>
        <onv:hotelLineId>ASMU03042015</onv:hotelLineId>
        <onv:firstName>NICOLE</onv:firstName>
        <onv:lastName>ROLAIN</onv:lastName>
        <onv:numberOfBags>1</onv:numberOfBags>
        <onv:status>enrolled</onv:status>
        <onv:hotelGuestId>41955886</onv:hotelGuestId>
        <onv:room>5613</onv:room>
        <onv:eligible>1</onv:eligible>
        <onv:partyGroupId>0</onv:partyGroupId>
        <onv:arrivalDate>2015-02-26</onv:arrivalDate>
        <onv:departureDate>2015-03-04</onv:departureDate>
        <onv:segments>
          <onv:segment>
              <onv:carrier>WN</onv:carrier>
              <onv:flightNumber>4280</onv:flightNumber>
              <onv:departureCity>MCO</onv:departureCity>
              <onv:departureDate>2015-03-04</onv:departureDate>
              <onv:departureTime>12:00 PM</onv:departureTime>
              <onv:operation>Add</onv:operation>
           </onv:segment>
        </onv:segments>
    </onv:request>
    </onv:document>
      </onv:ProcessData>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ProcessDataResponse xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
         <ProcessDataResult>
            <response xmlns="">Invalid Process Type</response>
         </ProcessDataResult>
      </ProcessDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Seems like you are getting confused. You said, you now get another error (another one than before), but they are simply the same. I am not taking more time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

A namespace declaration without a prefix declares the so-called *default namespace*. The default namespace is applied to the element where it is declared and to all child elements.

So in the following XML fragment

```
<parent xmlns="namespace">
    <child />
</parent>
```

both - the parent element and the child element are in the given namespace.

On the other hand, in the following XML fragment

```
<pre:parent xmlns:pre="namespace">
    <child />
</pre:parent>
```

you have a namespace declared with a prefix. This namespace is only applied to those elements who explicitly carry that prefix. In this example it is only the `parent` element, whereas the `child` element does not have a namespace.

---

In your XML documents you have a similar situation:

```
<ProcessData xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
    <document>
        <request xmlns="http://arinc/asd/OnvoyRegistration">
            ...
        </request>
    </document>
</ProcessData>
```

versus

```
<onv:ProcessData>
     <onv:document>
         <request>
            ...
        </request>
    </onv:document>
</onv:ProcessData>
```

with the prefix `onv` representing the same namespace as above.

In the second document, the `request` element has no namespace due to the missing prefix. In the first document it is in the default namespace declared somewhat higher in the hierarchy. In fact, the namespace declaration at the `request` element is redundant (in the first document).

Comment: Going with your explanation, I appended onv: with each child element. But now I am getting some other error and not the error which I was getting in the first.

Comment: If so, you should consider to update your question with what you did and what error you get.

Comment: I've updated the question with what U suggested and with responses.